# Perl: how to make date as argument to perl script

Tags: perl, shell, date, cron

Manually I run script from terminal like this:

```
# perl renew.pl 2014-06-09 data.xml
```

where 2014-06-09 is today's date and data.xml is file which script updates.

I'd like to run this script with cron, so I need inserting current date automatically.
I've tried something like

```
# perl renew.pl date +"%Y/%m/%d" data.xml <br>
or <br>
# perl renew.pl 'date +"%Y/%m/%d"' data.xml<br>
or <br>
# TODAY=`date '+%Y%m%d'`; perl renew.pl TODAY data.xml
```

But always got response like:

*Use of uninitialized value in numeric ge (>=) at /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/Date/Calc/PP.pm line 1547,  line
523. Date::Calc::PP::Add_Delta_Days(): Date::Calc::Add_Delta_Days(): not a valid date at renew.pl*

Are there any other variants to insert date as arguments?

Comment: Why don't you use built in functions instead of passing it at command line

Comment: You are using different date delimiters in your command-line example.  Without access to the code, it's hard to tell whether that is significant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what shell crond uses. Maybe it's your login shell? If it uses `sh` or `bash` like it does for me, you want

```
perl renew.pl "`date +"%Y/%m/%d"`" data.xml
```

or the more readable

```
perl renew.pl "$( date +"%Y/%m/%d" )" data.xml
```

`` `...` `` aka `$( ... )` execute the command therein, and interpolates its output. The surrounding double quotes escapes spaces and whatnot so that the result is passed as a single argument. (They're not needed here. I use them out of habit. Better safe than sorry.)

---

Let's look at what you tried:

- `perl renew.pl date +"%Y/%m/%d" data.xml` passes `date`, `+%Y/%m/%d` and `data.xml` as arguments.

  Missing the backticks mentioned earlier.
- `perl renew.pl 'date +"%Y/%m/%d"' data.xml` passes `date +"%Y/%m/%d"` and `data.xml` as aguments.

  Missing the backticks mentioned earlier.
- `TODAY=date '+%Y%m%d'; perl renew.pl TODAY data.xml` passes `TODAY` and `data.xml` as arguments.

  You finally used backticks, but you didn't actually use the variable in which you stored the result. You should have used `"$TODAY"` instead of `TODAY`.

Answer (score 1):

Could try either of the following in `bash`:

```
export TODAY=$(date +%Y%m%d); perl renew.pl $TODAY data.xml
```

Or without the intermediate variable:

```
perl renew.pl $(date +%Y%m%d) data.xml
```

You can also just edit your `renew.pl` to default to today's date when only called with 1 parameter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;

unshift @ARGV, localtime->strftime("%Y-%m-%d") if @ARGV == 1;
```

And then:

```
perl renew.pl data.xml
```